# webcam frame in a class to serialize and send

Tags: c#, opencv, networking, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a MessageData class and send it by network.
This class contain picture in bitmap that I need to display on a form.
The transmitted bitmap it's a frame that a webcam need to transmit several times each second by network to a WinForm.
This program it's a test and in future will be splitted in two parts, client part with receiver method and winform, and a server part with webcam and sender method.

Actually the Serializing and sending-receiving of the object-picture is not working, the winform is not showing any image if I force picture to pass from the serializing-network process instad of get it directly.
The webcam frames are managed with the Emgu.CV library, and locally it's working very well, but not by remote with the serialization sending of the frames.
All that follow is inside the namespace Idea:

```
[Serializable]
public class MessageData {
     public MessageData(Bitmap img){
         Picture = img;
     }
     public static Bitmap Picture { get; set; }
}    
[Serializable]
public class MessageSendData {
     public MessageSendData(Bitmap img){
         Picture = img;
     }
     public static Bitmap Picture { get; set; }
}

public partial class Idea : Form
{
    //declaring global variables
    private Capture capture;        //takes images from camera as image frames
    private bool captureInProgress; // checks if capture is executing
    private TcpListener ascolto;
    Bitmap bitmapricevuto;
    public Idea()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Idea_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();  //line 1
      //  CamImageBox.Image = byteArrayToImage(MyImageBytes(ImageFrame.ToBitmap()));
       // CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap(); 

            Thread r = new Thread(Ricevi);
            r.Start();
            MessageSendData.Picture = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
            Thread s = new Thread(Spedisci);
            s.Start();
            lock (MessageData.Picture){
                CamImageBox.Image = MessageData.Picture;
            }
    }





    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region if capture is not created, create it now
        if (capture == null)
        {
            try
            {
                capture = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (capture != null)
        {
            if (captureInProgress)
            {  //if camera is getting frames then stop the capture and set button Text
                // "Start" for resuming capture
                btnStart.Text = "Start!"; //
                Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
            }
            else
            {
                //if camera is NOT getting frames then start the capture and set button
                // Text to "Stop" for pausing capture
                btnStart.Text = "Stop";
                Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
            }

            captureInProgress = !captureInProgress;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (capture != null)
            capture.Dispose();
    }

    public static void Ricevi()
    {
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(address, 8585);
        listener.Start();
        Bitmap mia;
        try
        { 
            using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                while (true)
                {
                    lock (MessageData.Picture){
                        MessageData.Picture = (Bitmap)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { }
        return;
    }



    public static void Spedisci()
    {
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();  
        try  
        {    
            client.Connect(address, 8585); 

            // Retrieve the network stream.  
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            while(true)
            {
                lock (MessageSendData.Picture) { 
                formatter.Serialize(stream, MessageSendData.Picture);
               //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    /*
    public byte[] MyImageBytes(Image MyImage)
    {

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(MyImage, typeof(byte[]));

    }


    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] bytesArr)
    {
        MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(bytesArr);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(memstr);
        return img;
    }
    */


}
```

}
'

I've realized two methods: 1-First method convert the bitmap in a byte array. 2-Second method convert the byte array in a bitmap. Testing them directly without send the converted bytes by tcp network I see that all software are working. Now I've created two methods "Invia" and "Ricevi" that are sending and receiving with async methods the bytearrays by spliting them in stream of a length of 1024 each. My issue on compiling it's about the Async Task methods returned types. How to fix this threads Task async issues?
'

```
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {

         Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

         invia(MyImageBytes(ImageFrame.ToBitmap()));

         CamImageBox.Image = ricevi();

    }

    public byte[] MyImageBytes(Image MyImage)
    {

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(MyImage, typeof(byte[]));

    }
```

'

**Send (Invia) and Receive(Ricevi) methods last version here showed below are using the  chars converted to bytes array and appended to the bitmap bytes array for send and receive the bitmap. Actually I've issues during compiling:**

```
    public static void invia(byte[] bytetosend)
    {
                // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // Connect to a remote device.
    try {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress,11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
        try {
            sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            var mahByteArray = new ArrayList<byte>();
            mahByteArray.AddRange(bytetosend);
            string eof = "<EOF>";
            mahByteArray.Insert(0, Convert.ToByte(eof)); // Adds eof bytes to the beginning.
            byte[] msg = mahByteArray.ToArray();

            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));

            // Release the socket.
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();

        } catch (ArgumentNullException ane) {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}",ane.ToString());
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}",se.ToString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
    }
    }


    public static void ricevi()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        var scambioArray = new ArrayList();

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
        // host running the application.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
        // listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);

            // Start listening for connections.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                string eofr = "<EOF>";
                byte[] trova = Convert.ToByte(eofr);

                // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);


                    if (bytes.IndexOf(trova))
                    {
                        var mahByteArray = new ArrayList();
                        mahByteArray.AddRange(bytes);
                        mahByteArray.Remove(trova);
                        bytes = mahByteArray.ToArray();
                        break;
                    }
                    scambioArray.AddRange(bytes);
                }

                // Echo the data back to the client.
                byte[] msg = scambioArray.ToArray();

                MessageData.Picture = byteArrayToImage(msg);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does the receive know when all the data is received?  It is binary data so you must include a byte count along with the data so the receive know when the last character is received.

Comment: Test your code in small pieces. First write your serialized data to file, read it and show the image. If it works, goto next step and test your network code.

Comment: I've realized two methods: that converts the bitmap in a byte array and

Comment: I've realized two methods: 1-First method convert the bitmap in a byte array. 2-Second method convert the byte array in a bitmap.          Testing them directly without send the converted bytes by tcp network I see that all software are working.    Now I've created two methods "Invia" and "Ricevi" that are sending and receiving with async methods the bytearrays by spliting them in stream of a length of 1024 each.          My issue on compiling it's about the Async Task methods returned types. How to fix this threads Task async issues?

Comment: @jdweng   
I've realized two methods as visible in the new code that I've added on my original post: 1-First method convert the bitmap in a byte array. 2-Second method convert the byte array in a bitmap. Testing them directly without send the converted bytes by tcp network I see that all software are working. Now I've created two methods "Invia" and "Ricevi" that are sending and receiving with async methods the bytearrays by spliting them in stream of a length of 1024 each. My issue on compiling it's about the Async Task returned types. How to fix this threads Task async issues?

Comment: See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx.  The code if for sockets but will work for any class the inherits the socket like tcpclient or tcplistener.  Look at the ManualResetEvent() which is a block.  You don't have to return at type from an async event.  Just block the code until all characters are received.  I don't recommend using async on a send because there is no advantage over a sync send.

Comment: @jdweng that are helpfull examples, but I've a byte array of a Bitmap, not a string,then how I can add an EOF or tell to the other side when the length of the array ended and then when to stop? I need to tell to the receiver when the array is completed

Comment: Add a 4,6, or 8 byte count at beginning of binary data like 0x001234.  Then at receiver end  remove count and continue receiving until all the bytes are received.

Comment: #jdweng if I understand correctly I add 0x001234 at the first part of the bytes array (like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591329/c-sharp-how-to-add-byte-to-byte-array ) then on the receiver I check when I found the 0x001234 bytes then I stop to receive it and I cut the load part of bytes before the 0x001234 .    Is this right? or can I add the array load part length at the beginning of the array? this will work as an header that will tell the total length of the load part. Maybe there are just ready methods for this on the c# network tcp classes?

Comment: @jdweng if I understand correctly I add 0x001234 at the first part of the bytes array (like this stackoverflow.com/questions/5591329/… ) then on the receiver I check when I found the 0x001234 bytes then I stop to receive it and I cut the load part of bytes before the 0x001234 . Is this right? or can I add the array load part length at the beginning of the array? this will work as an header that will tell the total length of the load part. Maybe there are just ready methods for this on the c# network tcp classes?

Comment: No need to stop receiving.  You have a stream an can extract 4,6, or 8 bytes.  Then the rest of the data is the bitmap.   MSDN is very poor on complete solutions.  TCP is the transport layer and the byte count is really part of the application layer.  All of the MSDN TCP sample ignore the application layer.  Although I really like the 4 examples on the following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx.  The socket class can be replaced by any class that inherits socket like tcpclient and tcplistener.

Comment: @jdweng  I get the following errors during compile of the last version of the "Invia" and "Ricevi" methods visibles on the edit of my first post  Error6The non-generic type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments
Error8Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'byte[]'
Error9No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments 
Error10Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'byte[]' 
Error11Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'byte[]' Error12 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Idea.Idea.byteArrayToImage(byte[])'

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void invia(byte[] bytetosend)
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            // Connect to a remote device.
            try
            {
                // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
                // This example uses port 11000 on the local computer.
                IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

                // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
                Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
                try
                {
                    sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                    Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                        sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                    // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                    var mahByteArray = new List<byte>();
                    mahByteArray.AddRange(bytetosend);
                    string eof = "<EOF>";
                    mahByteArray.Insert(0, Convert.ToByte(eof)); // Adds eof bytes to the beginning.
                    byte[] msg = mahByteArray.ToArray();

                    // Send the data through the socket.
                    int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                    // Receive the response from the remote device.
                    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                    // Release the socket.
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();

                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        public void ricevi()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            List<byte> bytes = (new Byte[1024]).ToList();
            List<byte> scambioArray = new List<byte>();

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
            // host running the application.
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
            // listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);

                // Start listening for connections.
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                    string eofr = "<EOF>";
                    List<byte> trova = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eofr).ToList();

                    // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                    while (true)
                    {
                        bytes = (new byte[1024]).ToList();
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes.ToArray());


                        if (bytes.Contains(trova[0]))
                        {
                            List<byte> mahByteArray = new List<byte>();
                            mahByteArray.AddRange(bytes);
                            mahByteArray.Remove(trova[0]);
                            bytes = mahByteArray.ToArray().ToList();
                            break;
                        }
                        scambioArray.AddRange(bytes);
                    }

                    // Echo the data back to the client.
                    byte[] msg = scambioArray.ToArray();
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(msg);    
                    MessageData.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: I've used the ricevi and invia procedure that you suggest. I've started the receiver server procedure by a delegate in a lamda expression thread with the BeginInvoke, then without use a callback or the EndInvoke I've tryed to send bitmap image byte array to the server by the invio procedure. The program compile but without image showed on the WinForm. The webcam is working and the firewall is disabled. I will procede to debug each part of the program for understand where my Bitmap frame stop. Here there is the program that compile but not show the frame image.