# How to declare a byte ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist, byte

I am trying to do

```
var mahByteArray = new ArrayList<byte>();
```

And it does not work. 
It says this:

> The non-generic type 'System.Collectios.ArrayList' cannot be used with
>   type arguments

What is the proper way to do declare a byte `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing **Java ArrayList collections** with  **C# List generic collections**. Both are used to declare collections, but the first one is used in Java as being a type defined in the generic class List for Collections framework and in the last one is used in C# language as an implicit generic type.

So, you must declare as being a `List` type. See details on [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var mahByteArray = new List<byte>();
```

or

```
List<byte> mahByteArray = new List<byte>() { 2, 3, 4 };
```

Answer (score 3):

sure you can use a `ArrayList`

```
var mahByteArray = new ArrayList();
mahByteArray.Add((byte) 230);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<>` isn't generic. You can use generic `List<>` instead

```
var mahByteArray = new List<byte>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is not generic. Use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` instead. The [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.100).aspx) class is the generic equivalent of the `ArrayList` class. It implements the `IList<T>` generic interface using an array whose size is dynamically increased as required.

```
var mahByteArray = new List<byte>();
```

Also take a look at this: [Difference between ArrayList and Generic List.](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Difference-between-ArrayList-and-Generic-List-in-C-Net-and-VBNet.aspx)