# Add bytes to byte array C#

Tags: c#, memory, byte

How could I add the following bytes to a c# byte array?

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Does this make sense?

```
public void updateBytes(string exeName, int value)
{
    long baseaddress = GetBaseAddress(exeName, exeName + ".exe");
    long pointer = GetPointerAddress(baseaddress + 0x04105320, new int[] { value });

    byte[] intBytes = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00";

    WriteBytes(pointer, intBytes);
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: This doesn't even compile as of yet. `byte[]` != `string`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# how to add byte to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591329/c-sharp-how-to-add-byte-to-byte-array)

Comment: It is better to use a list object which has an add method than to use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first of all you have a `string` and you want to assign this to `byte[]` which is a big nono. If you cannot change this to `byte[]` by hand ( because of some weird protocol or something ) you can do this like that :

```
// assign bytes to string
string meBytes = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00";
// split them by spaces
string[] hexBytes = meBytes.Split(new char[] { (char)0x20 });
// extract bytes
byte[] bytes = meBytes.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();
// now you can write them into stream
WriteBytes(pointer, bytes);
```

You can even  do this in two lines :

```
string meBytes = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 04 05 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00";
WriteBytes(pointer, meBytes.Split(new char[] { (char)0x20 }).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray());
```

Comment: `meBytes.Split(0x20)` *doesn't compile*: `0x20` is of type `int`, when `char` is expected; `0x20` is *magic number antipattern* (what does it stand for?) when `' '` (space) is evident

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you for pointing that. Fixed it. And `0x20` ( as everyone knows ) is just a space character and it is more convenient ( for me and people i know ) to write bytes/chars in hex format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you don't really want to **add** items to an array but **create/initialize** an array with given values.

You can use the following syntax to initialize an array:

```
byte[] intBytes = {0,0,0,4,5,1,1 /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want parse `string` into array of byte (`byte[]`) you can use *Linq*:

```
string source = "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 05...";

byte[] intBytes = source
  .Split(' ')
  .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16))
  .ToArray();
```